# sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: no such table: SubSection error

Tags: sqlite, ionic5

**This is my creating data base function**
I don't understand why the following code shows error like this:
still geting error in ionic5
I open the database, but when i check if the statement is OK, i get the following error.
sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: no such table: SubSection error

```
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.sqlite.create({
        name: this.db_name3,
        location: 'default'
      }).then((sqLite: SQLiteObject) => {
        this.dbInstance = sqLite;
        sqLite.executeSql(`
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${this.db_subSection} (
          SubSectionName varchar(255),
          SectionName varchar(255),
          Description varchar(255),

          DateString varchar(255),
          MonthString varchar(255),
          YearString varchar(255),

          CreatedAt Date,
          UpdatedAt Date,
          isActive boolean,
          isDelete boolean
        )`, [])
          .then((res) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(res));
            console.log("Get res subSection Data",res);
          })
          .catch((error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)));
          console.log("error subSection data");
          
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)));
  });   
}

i am using SQLite in ionic5 service file for accessing data on front end.
I don't understand why the following code shows error like this:
still geting error in ionic
I open the database, but when i check if the statement is OK, i get the following error.
sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: no such table: SubSection error
```